# Why is this getting "invalid argument" error in IE8? (window.open)

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

```
            function popupLink(link){                
               var popup = window.open(link,'Facebook Share','menubar=0,directories=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1,status=0,location=0,width=500,height=350');
                if(!popup){
                    return true;
                }else{                    
                    return false;
                }
            };

 popupLink('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmsn.com%2F');
```

I just want to pop up a link...

Comment: What link is being passed to it?  Can you add a bit of the code that is calling it?

Comment: not on my side!, what is the value of link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Window names cannot include spaces in IE. Change `'Facebook Share'` to `'FacebookShare'`

Comment: Nice.  That one puzzled me.  "Works in Chrome, not in IE8."  I wasn't surprised, of course, but thanks for the info. +1